# Дополненная реальность в Android с помощью SDK Vuforia

Tags: android, java, vuforia, c++

Всем доброго дня.
В приложении нужно использовать дополненную реальность. 
Перешарил весь интернет и нашел отличную SDK [ссылка](https://ar.qualcomm.at/sdk/android)
Остановился на шаге **Step 3: Compiling & Running a Vuforia Sample App** 
Конкретнее здесь **Compile the Shared Object**
Никак не могу понять, что нужно делать, в связи с этим не работает приложение.
Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Речь идет о сборке NDKашной вставки в рассматриваемом примере. Надо просто "зайти" в соответствующий каталог и набрать с линуксовой (или цигвиновской) консоли `ndk-build` на выходе получится линуксовая библиотека `*.so`, которая далее будет использована при сборке джавешного APK

Comment: а если у меня windows?

Comment: под виндой все тоже самое

Comment: @Wars если под виндой, то на то имеется cygwin - грубо говоря эмулятор консоли линукса под виндой

Comment: не нужен там уже никакой цигвин. Распаковали и в бой.